# Word that represents the meaning of "Has been permitted access"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word in English which conveys the meaning of 'Has been permitted access' / 'Has access granted'`?

Example:

- Devices with permitted access
- Users with permitted access

Looking for something like *WORD devices*

Use case is: User has a list of devices and has given access to some of them.

Comment: Hello, vodofon. Single word requests on ELU need to be accompanied by a **sentence** including a _____ where the required word will fit. You seem to specify _two_ word-classes.

Comment: This is a "help me pick a good name for something in software" question, which is inherently offtopic here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply ***authorized*** to both *users* and *devices*. it means:

> having official permission to do something or for something to happen: ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/authorized))

For *devices*, however, ***[approved](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/approved)*** might work better.